# Google Maps API - Place animation

Tags: google-maps-api-3

Is it possible to animate map center from one location to another during 20 seconds? And if so, how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [google.maps.Map#panTo](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Map) method will change the center using animation.

> Changes the center of the map to the given LatLng. If the change is less than both the width and height of the map, the transition will be smoothly animated.

However, you cannot control the animation delay/interval with the map#panTo method.  I think you can hack a custom delay using `window.setTimeout()`:

Checkout the custom 5 second animation of flying from San Fran to Vegas @ http://jsfiddle.net/stevejansen/g6NSS/

It's not perfect, but, it seems to work reasonably well for me in Chrome.

```js
function initialize() {
    var origin = new google.maps.LatLng(37.774, -122.419),
        dest = new google.maps.LatLng(36.114, -115.172),
        canvas = document.getElementById("map-canvas"),
        options = {
            center: origin,
            zoom: 8,
            mapTypeControl: false
        };

    google.maps.visualRefresh = true;
    var map = new google.maps.Map(canvas, options);

    google.maps.event.addDomListenerOnce(map, 'idle', function () {
        panTo(map, dest, 5000);
    });
}


function panTo(map, dest, delay) {
    var GOOGLE_PAN_DELAY = 30,
        /* the native Google Maps milliseconds */
        cycles = delay / GOOGLE_PAN_DELAY,
        interval = delay / cycles,
        origin = map.getCenter(),
        waypoints = [],
        temp,
        lat,
        lng;

    // compute the change in lat/long, and divide across N cycles
    lat = (dest.lat() - origin.lat()) / cycles;
    lng = (dest.lng() - origin.lng()) / cycles;

    // starting at origin, add N-1 intermediate waypoints that are equidistance apart
    temp = origin;
    for (var i = 0; i < cycles - 1; i++) {
        temp = new google.maps.LatLng(temp.lat() + lat, temp.lng() + lng);
        waypoints.push(temp);
    }
    // make sure the last waypoint is the actual dest
    waypoints.push(dest);

    function pan() {
        var waypoint;

        if (waypoints.length === 0) return;

        waypoint = waypoints.shift();

        map.panTo(waypoint);

        window.setTimeout(pan, interval);
    }

    pan();
}


google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Steve Jansen for your panTo function. I've slightly modified it in order to provide an easy-in movement. I include it here in case someone finds it useful.

```
function panTo(map, dest, delay) {
            var GOOGLE_PAN_DELAY = 30,
            /* the native Google Maps milliseconds */
                cycles = delay / GOOGLE_PAN_DELAY,
                interval = delay / cycles,
                origin = map.getCenter(),
                waypoints = [],
                temp,
                step,
                lat,
                lng;

            // compute the change in lat/long, and divide across N cycles
            lat = (dest.lat() - origin.lat()) / cycles;
            lng = (dest.lng() - origin.lng()) / cycles;

            // starting at origin, add N-1 intermediate waypoints that are equidistance apart
            temp = origin;
            for (var i = 0; i < cycles - 1; i++) {
                step = cycles / ((cycles - i)*(cycles - i));
                temp = new google.maps.LatLng(temp.lat() + (lat * step), temp.lng() + (lng * step));
                waypoints.push(temp);
            }
            // make sure the last waypoint is the actual dest
            waypoints.push(dest);

            function pan() {
                var waypoint;

                if (waypoints.length === 0) return;

                waypoint = waypoints.shift();

                map.panTo(waypoint);

                window.setTimeout(pan, interval);
            }

            pan();
        }
```